# Pourquoi ne pronononce-t-on pas le 'p' dans les mots baptême, baptiser, baptiste, etc

Tags: prononciation, religion

[Selon le dictionnaire de l'AF](https://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/dico1look.pl?strippedhw=p#:%7E:text=Le%20p%20est%20une%20consonne%20labiale.&text=Quand%20le%20P%20est%20suivi,%2C%20farmacie%2C%20oesofage%2C%20etc.)

> Dans l'intérieur des mots, entre deux consonnes, il est souvent muet, comme dans Sculpture, Dompteur, Prompt, Temps, Corps. À la fin des mots, il est souvent aussi muet, comme dans Coup, Loup, Galop, Champ. Toutefois, dans Beaucoup et Trop, il peut s'unir à la voyelle initiale du mot suivant. Il y a beaucoup à dire. Il y aurait trop à dire.

Cependant, je me demande pour quelle raison dans les mots baptême, baptiser, baptiste p ne se prononce pas.

Comment: En s'attendrait à ce que la même lénition se produirait en fin de syllabe intérieure qu'en fin de mot. Mais il faudrait examiner un plus grand échantillon pour déterminer s'il s'agit d'une règle ou d'une exception dans ce cas-ci.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Je crois que c'est comme sept. (p ne se prononce pas).

Comment: Néanmoins si le *p* ne se prononce pas dans « sept », il se prononce dans « septembre » !

Comment: @Toto Donc considérons seulement les mots de la question:-)! Tous proviennent du grec ; le p y se prononce. Pourquoi en français p ne se prononce pas ?

Comment: Je trouve "\dɔ̃.tœʁ\ ou \dɔ̃p.tœʁ\" dans les dictionnaires mais je crois ne jamais avoir entendu \dɔ̃.tœʁ\. Étrange comme choix d'exemple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Baptême et ses dérivés sont des emprunts savants au Latin médiéval. Comme la grande majorité des emprunts similaires, il s'est fait avec une phonologie adaptée au français de l'époque, qui tendait à simplifier les groupes de consonnes, donc comme /ba'tɛsmə/ puis /batɛːmə/ (1). Les orthographes avec et sans le p étymologique sont présentes très tôt ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bapt%C3%AAme)).

Mais dès la Renaissance (2) apparaît une tendance à réintroduire les consonnes simplifiées en ancien Français dans les emprunts au Latin, que ce soit par influence de l'orthographe ou par purisme classistique (la reconstruction de la prononciation latine classique par Érasme et d'autres y est pour beaucoup), un processus qui se poursuit jusqu'à nos jours (la langue étant devenue beaucoup plus tolérante des groupes consonantiques que par le passé, surtout en Français contemporain).

Le plus rare le mot et le moins usuel dans la vie de tous les jours, le plus forte cette tendance. Le baptême étant une cérémonie importante et populaire dans les sociétés francophone restées très catholiques jusqu'à récemment, la prononciation originale s'est maintenue, sauf dans le plutôt savant adjectif *baptismal* qui est parfois prononcé avec /p/.

À noter que la notice du dictionnaire de l'Académie est assez brouillonne: elle mélange les consonnes graphiques des voyelles nasales avec celles prononcées de sculpture ou de corps et omet de mentionner que des prononciations avec /p/ de sculpture, dompteur ou prompt(ement) s'entendent fréquemment. Mais c'est vrai que le p purement orthographique de baptême est inhabituel.

(1) Autres exemples dont la consonne a depuis été restaurée: a**d**versaire, o**b**scur, dra**ch**me, **p**saume, ainsi que tous les mots en x, originellement prononcé /s/, i.e. texte était /tɛs.tə/. D'autres mots dont la consonne est disparue même de l'orthographe sont par exemple tisane (< ptisanam) ou flemme (< phlegmam)

(2) le processus commence plus tôt, avec les réformes de Charlemagne: précédemment, on empruntait animaliam as armaille, ordinem as ordre, gramaticam as grammaire, après on essaie de se rapprocher un peu plus de la forme latine, particulièrement dans l'orthographe qui commence alors à s'éloigner de la prononciation. C'est cette orthographe latinisante introduite à l'époque carolingienne qui finit par influencer la prononciation 7 siècles plus tard.

Comment: Verbe nécessaire : « Plus rare est le mot, moins il est utilisé au quotidien (tautologie : que ce soit un mot de la vie de tous les jours ou d'un domaine spécialisé, la rareté est liée à son usage par les personnes concernées) et plus cette règle s'applique. »