# Quels sont les mots les plus difficiles à prononcer pour les français ?

Tags: prononciation

Il y a des phrases difficiles à prononcer (chaussettes de l'archiduchesse) mais je n'ai pas trouvé de liste de mots français (à part pour les étrangers, ce n'est pas la question) qui le sont.

Même les mots les plus longs ne semblent pas particulièrement difficiles une fois qu'on les connait.
Doit on se tourner vers les mots d'origine slave ? (je me souviens avoir eu du mal avec le polonais)

Comment: Je n'ai de liste mais un exemple: `exégèse`

Comment: Les mots assez longs peuvent poser un problème si on doit les dire rapidement comme *anticonstitutionnellement*

Answer (score 2):

Un mot qui peut poser problème est:

- Abracadabrantesque

Il y a aussi les mots parfois ou souvent prononcés différemment de ce qu'attend la norme :

- Abasourdi
- Carrousel
- Couenne
- Dégingandé
- Etc.
- Juin
- Lumbago
- Moelleux
- Poêler
- Gageure
- Magnat
- Œdème, œsophage, œnologue...
- Pupille
- Puzzle
- Reblochon
- Suggestion

Quelques noms propres:

- Bruxelles
- Laguiole
- Enghien

La rectification orthographique de 1990 a entériné certaines prononciations comme
*féérique* (au lieu de *féerique*)

Sources: [eklablog](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/vous-dites-a3737989), [topito](https://www.topito.com/top-mots-francais-toujours-mal-prononces)

Comment: Difficile pour beaucoup : otho-rhino-laryngologiste, assassinassions, ubuesque, archiépiscopal  — Pour votre liste : immixtion, damné, lichen, geôle, ignominie.

Comment: Autres exemples : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43386/pourquoi-ne-pronononce-t-on-pas-le-p-dans-les-mots-bapt%c3%aame-baptiser-baptiste

Comment: @jlliagre tu as listé des mots que l'on prononce facilement de manière incorrecte, je pensais à des mots que l'ont prononce difficilement de manière correcte. Doit on considérer qu'il n'en existe pas au seins d'une même langue, car on ne créé ni n'utilise de tels mots ?

Comment: Certains mots sont plus difficiles à prononcer que d'autres, mais cette difficulté se manifeste plutôt chez les enfants. Je pense par exemple à *aéroport* souvent prononcé *aréoport*. Les mots étrangers adoptés en français font l'objet d'une adaptation qui les rend normalement facilement prononçables. Certains mots techniques qui ne sont pas connus par le locuteur peuvent entraîner des difficultés de prononciation mais ce sera plus par difficulté de lecture: *désoxyribonucléique* ou *acétylsalicylique*, *eicosapentaénoïque*.

Comment: On peut ajouter des mots "inventés" tels que *apopathodiaphulatophobie*, *hexakosioihexekontahexaphobique*, *schoïnopentaxophile*...

Answer (score -2):

Words in isolation are one thing and words in sentences another. Here is a typical sentence, conceived expressly to make salient the possible difficulties that word combinations may cause.

- Un chasseur sachant chasser doit savoir chasser sans son chien. (*It must be said at normal speed.*)
- Seize chaises sèchent ([réf.](https://laliste.net/14-phrases-presque-impossibles-a-prononcer-a-voix-haute-essayez-osez/))

Comment: The OP is aware of this kind of sentences. The question is about isolated words.